# The "main" div around the options html element does not allow to insert them into parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

> I have 2 dropdowns as below:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 offset-3 text-center">
          <select v-model="animation1">
            <option selected hidden>In Animation</option>
            <app-dropdown-options></app-dropdown-options>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 offset-3 text-center">
        <select v-model="animation2">
          <option selected hidden>Out Animation</option>
          <app-dropdown-options></app-dropdown-options>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> Because i dont want to repeat myself i have create a component which has these options as below :

```
<template>

        <div>
          <option value="animated bounce">bounce</option>
          <option value="animated wobble">wobble</option>
          <option value="animated bounceInLeft">bounceInLeft</option>
          <option value="animated bounceOutDown">bounceOutDown</option>
          <option value="animated fadeIn">fadeIn</option>
          <option value="animated fadeInLeftBig">fadeInLeftBig</option>
          <option value="animated fadeInUpBig">fadeInUpBig</option>
          <option value="animated fadeOutLeft">fadeOutLeft</option>
        </div>
    </template>
```

> After that,i use the child component on selects.The only problem is on child component in which the main div,around the options cause problem.
>   I have try a lot to find a solution but i can't so i decided to publish my problem

Comment: Share live demo or any fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to have the whole select inside of child component and pass to it "animation in" and "animation out" where these are the text of two selects respectively,with props.Even if is the same component,Vue treat for the component as unique for each select

> Parent component:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 offset-3 text-center">
      <app-dropdown-options passedInOrOut="In Animation" @optionWasChanged="firstAnimation($event)"></app-dropdown-options>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 offset-3 text-center">
      <app-dropdown-options passedInOrOut="Out Animation" @optionWasChanged="secondAnimation($event)"></app-dropdown-options>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Child Component:

```
<template>
  <select v-model="optionSelected">
    <option selected hidden>{{anim}}</option>
    <option value="animated bounce">bounce</option>
    <option value="animated wobble">wobble</option>
    <option value="animated bounceInLeft">bounceInLeft</option>
    <option value="animated bounceOutDown">bounceOutDown</option>
    <option value="animated fadeIn">fadeIn</option>
    <option value="animated fadeInLeftBig">fadeInLeftBig</option>
    <option value="animated fadeInUpBig">fadeInUpBig</option>
    <option value="animated fadeOutLeft">fadeOutLeft</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

> For those who want to see the scripts of parent and child component:

Js of parent Component:

```
<script>
import Options from './dropdownOptions.vue';
  export default{
    components:{
      'app-dropdown-options':Options
    },
    data(){
      return{
        show:true,
        animation1:'empty',
        animation2:'empty',
        animate:'animated bounce',
        inOrOut:'In'
      }
    },
    methods:{
      firstAnimation(animation){
        this.animation1 = animation;
      },
      secondAnimation(animation){
        this.animation2 = animation;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

JS for child Component:

```
<script>
    export default{
    props:['passedInOrOut'],
    data(){
      return{
        anim:this.passedInOrOut,
        option:''
      }
    },
    computed:{
      optionSelected:{
        get(){
          return this.option = this.anim;
        },
        set(option){
          this.option = option;
          this.$emit('optionWasChanged',this.option);
        }
      }
    }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are really reusing here is the `data`, so rather than creating a component with `options` you should use a [`mixin`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) and loop through the data using `v-for`:

```
// SelectData Mixin
const SelectData = {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [{
        value: 'animated bounce', text: 'bounce'
      }, {
        value: 'animated wobble', text: 'wobble'
      }, {
        value: 'animated bounceInLeft', text: 'bounceInLeft'
      }, {
        value: 'animated bounceOutDown', text: 'bounceOutDown'
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Then to use it you simply do:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [SelectData],
  data: {
    selected: 'animated bounce'
  }
})
```

Because a mixin is merged into your Vue instance, `options` is now available in your template:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dL7zxjc8/

Of course, if you only need this data in one component, then you could simply declare the options in that Vue instance and forget about the mixin.

Comment: Ofcourse we have mixins!i was trying to fix it on html way and i found a way i will post it as answer.Usefull asnwer thanks